# Changing OpenGL Android to LibGDX OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a project which has a native android OpenGL implementation. MyView extends GLSurfaceView and MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer. I'm not satisfied with the implementation, because it was done in a hurry and is improper. I'd like to change it to a LibGDX implementation. A couple of questions, is it worth it? I'm not using any native code for my existing opengl implementation, I'm not really familiar with C/C++ code. So will I see a performance improvement by changing over to LibGDX. Second, how hard is it to do. I'm just starting out with LibGDX, got the app to run on my device. Am I better off investing time in NDK or LibGDX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not really familiar with C/C++, then it's probably not going to help your project to switch to the NDK. You're going to slow down your progress to make any framework change, and adding a new language is only going to compound the delay.

As for moving to libgdx, that might be a worthwhile investment of time. The main advantage I found when switch from native android to libgdx was that you could run your app straight on your desktop. The emulator is too slow to run games, so normally all your testing has to be on your phone, which is slow and aggravating. With libgdx, it runs right away, and all you have to do is export a different project to get an apk. I found that was also a good way to test screen sizes: you can just resize the window instead of creating a bunch of virtual devices.

I guess the main disadvantage to running libgdx is that you don't get direct access to the android framework. I worked around this (using different Activities for menus, for example) by adding those to the android project. The libgdx project was essentially just the core of the game.

Comment: Thanks Steve, if I were to add In-App purchases and/or Ads, is it as simple as native android. Create a PaymentActivity, call is with startActivityForResult(...) and get the callback in onActivityResult. Or like you say, I'll have to work around it? And one more important thing I missed, since Android requires us to reload all the texture data onResume (currently doing it in onSurfaceChanged), do I have to do it or will the framework take care of it? Thanks again

Comment: I've never worked with ads, but I see [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx). For the payments, you'll need to do all the `Activity` stuff from android code, so maybe from a menu or something, but not directly from the libgdx activity/application. And for textures, I think there's both managed and unmanaged textures--I only worked with manaaged, and those are reloaded for you. [This](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TheArchitecture) is a really good overview for what to expect with libgdx.